# CUDA not available on Deep Learning AMI (DLAMI) running on an Amazon EC2 P2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, python, aws, amazon-ec2, cuda

I am running the [Ubuntu 18.04 Deep Learning AMI (DLAMI)](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-x5nivojpquy6y) on AWS, and am attempting to run it on a `p2.xlarge` EC2 instance, but CUDA is not available in my Python interpreter. I was assuming that CUDA would work out of the box, since it's an AMI that is supposedly designed to work with torch/CUDA.

I am trying to run my code within the `pytorch_latest_p37` conda environment that comes pre-installed with the DLAMI. This uses Python3.7, and comes with PyTorch 1.7.1 built with CUDA 11.0.:

```
ubuntu@ip-111-21-33-212:~$ source activate pytorch_latest_p37
```

The output of `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc` both seem to indicate that CUDA is installed:

```
(pytorch_latest_p37) ubuntu@ip-111-21-33-212:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun Jul 18 07:51:09 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.119.03   Driver Version: 450.119.03   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P8    30W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+


(pytorch_latest_p37) ubuntu@ip-111-21-33-212:~$ nvcc --version                  nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
```

But `torch.cuda.is_available()` is returning `false` in ipython and  I am getting errors saying that torch was not compiled with CUDA support:

```
(pytorch_latest_p37) ubuntu@ip-111-21-33-212:~$ ipython
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import torch

In [2]: torch.cuda.is_available()
Out[2]: False

In [3]: torch.zeros(1).cuda()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0904fac96cba> in <module>
----> 1 torch.zeros(1).cuda()

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py in _lazy_init()
    164                 "Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. " + msg)
    165         if not hasattr(torch._C, '_cuda_getDeviceCount'):
--> 166             raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
    167         if _cudart is None:
    168             raise AssertionError(

AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

What is going on here? What do I need to do to get CUDA running on P2/P3 instances?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I actually had to give up on the project I was working on because of this. If you do end up finding a solution, I would very much appreciate it if you could post it here so I can dust off my old project :)

Comment: Experiencing the same, but on a Linux AMI